# java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 al generar el apk del juego (libgdx)

Tags: java, android-studio, apk, libgdx, build.gradle

**No me permite generar el apk de mi juego , cuando intento generarlo obtengo este error :**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**Aqui mi build.gradle:**

android {

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
compileSdkVersion 26
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mygdx.game"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {

```
file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
    if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if(outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
```

}

task run(type: Exec) {

```
def path
def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    if (sdkDir) {
        path = sdkDir
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }
} else {
    path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
}
def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher'
```

}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.

eclipse {

```
// need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
// ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
    }
}

jdt {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}

classpath {
    plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
}

project {
    name = appName + "-android"
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
```

}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.

idea {

```
module {

    sourceDirs += file("src");
    scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

    iml {
        withXml {
            def node = it.asNode()
            def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
            builder.current = node;
            builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                    configuration {
                        option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Cabe destacar que mi proyecto funciona bien al momento de correrlo tanto como en el launcher de escritorio como por depuración al movil.**

Comment: Parece que estas utilizando el jre para compilar, revisa en el android-studio la configuración del JDK

Comment: Ajeno explicate mejor porfavor , llevo ya un tiempo considerable con este problema.